# Infinite loop when inserting and selecting from same Esper window

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

Is there a way to insert into the same window that is part of the from clause within Esper?

For example ...

```
insert into HaltEvent
select haltType(t, w) type
from StockEvent#lastevent as t
left outer join HaltEvent#keepall w
```

Above `haltType` is a user defined function that is dependent `HaltEvent`. Since there is a `left outer join`, this will at least return at least the one `StockEvent` with `HaltEvent` as `null`. In the event there is a `HaltEvent` for a stock, the `haltType` will take into account the previous `HaltEvent` attributes.

In the above query, since `HaltEvent` is included as part of `keepall`, and endless set of `HaltEvents` is created.

Can I tell Esper to do something like, "Ignore the events added as part of this query"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there isn't such a "ignore events", but why insert into HaltEvent in the first place?

Comment: There are two types of `HaltEvents` ... STOP and START. START is only published after a STOP event has happened. So if `StockEvent` is below the limit for `HaltEvent`, do nothing. If `StockEvent` then is above the limit, publish STOP. And then when `StockEvent` goes below the limit in HaltEvent, then publish a `HaltEvent` with START.

Comment: Thanks for the answer about not being able to ignore events!